# Ruby on Rails 4. Model conditional validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have model with some validation rules:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :zip_code, presence: true, length: {is: 5}, numericality: {only_integer: true, :greater_than => 0}
end
```

And when zip_code is blank i don't need to perform other zip_code validations (it is redundant and all other validation messages on user page look very strange if zip_code is blank)

How can i implement this logic? i need to validate `length, is_integer and greater_than only if zip_code is not blank?` and i need to show only `zip_code can't be blank` message on user page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like

```
validates :zip_code, presence: true
validates :zip_code, length: {is: 5}, numericality: {only_integer: true, :greater_than => 0}, :if => :zip_code?
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Done, i had to wait 3 min to mark it as answer. Thx a lot